# PHP CLI: what directory?

Tags: php

I have a php cli script which is executed from /, but the script lies in /opt/script/script.php. How can I get the dynamic location of the script from within the script

```
$location = ... (Get the location of the script) 
echo $location == '/opt/script' ? 'YAY' : 'Stupid';
```

Output

```
YAY
```

That kind of thing.

Comment: Do you mean by "location"  the physical location of the current script file or the current working directory?

Comment: How is the location of the script *dynamic*? Doesn't it reside on the same place all the time?

Comment: I mean where the current script file is located, not the working directory. And @hakre I have to move the script some times and I don't want to rewrite my script everytime I move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__)` (or `__DIR__` in newer versions) should be enough. You can find further reference at the [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Choose what you need, you might be looking for `__FILE__` (a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) containing the filename of the current file) according to your comment:

```
echo 'Filename (as called): ', var_dump($argv[0]);

echo 'Current working directory (normally the directory called in): ', var_dump(getcwd());

echo 'Path of the script: ', var_dump(__FILE__);

echo 'Directory of the script: ', var_dump(__DIR__);
```